# What is the best way to learn & understand Japan's transportation system before arriving

Tags: japan, japan-rail, japanese-visitors

I'm traveling to Japan in March and will be staying for 2 weeks. I plan on using public transportation + car rental to travel and see as much as I can (recommendations welcome as well!) and I have read that the public transportation can be confusing. Are there any good tips or suggestions on how I can learn and prep beforehand?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and as such, questions that ask for open-ended lists of suggestions, hints, tips, examples, and so forth where every answer is equally valid are not well-suited to the format. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: There are any number of tourist guides for local transportation in different cities, which a simple web search should turn up. For what it's worth, I found it easier to navigate Tokyo's train system as a first-time visitor than New York's, and having taken trains and buses in Tokyo, Osaka, Kyoto, and Nagoya, I found the signage and announcements clear and the staff generally helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you can make your question more specific.  In particular, how well can you read or understand Japanese?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get around is the Japan Rail pass https://japanrailpass.net/en/ . You buy a pass for a given time period, class and region) and can ride as much as you want. The pass works on most Japan railways and also a lot of local trains in Tokyo.

Timetables can be found easily with an app http://www.hyperdia.com/ . We would often just walk to the train station look up the next train and jump on it. If you want to reserve seats, you need to stop in a ticket office.

Caveat: Covid makes for a very fluid and unpredictable travel situation. Rules and conditions can change quickly and without advanced warning.